# Cannot paste image from clipboard any more

Tags: bug, status-norepro, image-upload

The new image UI does not allow to paste an image **via the clipboard** any more.

This means I have to save the image first, then click on the UI, search the image on disk and click <kbd>OK</kbd>. In total this means what could previously been done via a single <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> / <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> now requires at least three clicks + some typing + one click / two clicks (+n clicks to navigate to the folder of the saved file). Plus, some clicks to delete the image on disk again.

If relevant: I'm using Opera version 56.0.3051.52 on Windows.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links?cb=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I downloaded Opera 56.0.3051.70 - not *quite* the same version you're using, but pretty close.

[image: animation of pasting into the question editor on Gardening & Landscaping, using Opera]

This is running on Windows 10: I was able to paste an image into both the upload pane itself, and trigger the upload pane with pre-populated image by pasting into the editor.

Comment: Oh! So it seems, this is non-reproducible. You are right, it works for me too, but not in all cases. I would need to find out what the difference is then. In the meantime, consider this as solved.

Comment: I couldn’t paste either. MacOS with Safari. Copied image from MATLAB window. Will try tonight to copy from a different source to see if that is the issue.

Comment: There are [some other reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317596/stackoverflows-new-image-upload-does-not-work-on-mac-safari) of issues with Safari specifically, @Cris; I don't have access to Safari, but it seems likely that there's something unique about how it's handling clipboard data here - please add anything you observe to the report there so we can track this down.

Comment: *and trigger the upload pane with pre-populated image by pasting into the editor* - wah, all these seconds lost bringing up the upload pane manually... good job! #TIL